# MultipleObjectsReturned at / - Django allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm trying to make authentication to my Django app via Google using Allauth. However, django throws an error - MultipleObjectsReturned at /. Error occures in
`<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}?next=/">Login with Google</a>`

Tracelog:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\1PROJECTS\py\OAuth-authorization-demo\venv\Lib\site-packages\allauth\socialaccount\adapter.py, line 290, in get_app
apps = self.list_apps(request, provider=provider, client_id=client_id)
        if len(apps) > 1:
            raise MultipleObjectsReturned
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Local vars:

```
SocialApp: <class 'allauth.socialaccount.models.SocialApp'>
apps: [<SocialApp: Google>, <SocialApp: >]
```

apps array is indeed longer than 1, but second object is empty and i can't find where it coming from. SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS has only one key "google".

Checked SITE_ID variable, Site.object.all() has only 1 object.

Comment: You might have a better time over at https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues